# DateTime to UK Date with dash

Tags: c#, datetime, view, tostring

I'm using a DateTime type in a view

```
(DateTime) => <%= process.Invoice.SubmittedDate %>
```

Will be shown as this: 28/08/2013 => mm/dd/yyyy
But I need it like this: 2013-08-28
I found many thinks like .ToString("yyyy/mm/dd") but

1. found nothing with dashes
2. this don't work.
   Error: "No overload method for 'ToString' takes 1 arguments"

I just want to change some views of this site for our local plant and have no idea of the other parts or mvc. (Not my code)

Can somebody help with a few hints?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Can you please show [MCVE] at least? It is a little bit hard to understand as such.

Comment: Be aware, `mm` specifier is for minutes but `MM` specifier is for months.

Comment: If it says _No overload method for 'ToString' takes 1 arguments_ the instance you use is _probably_ **not** a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `SubmittedDate` is a `DateTime` then you can use `ToString()`:

```
process.Invoice.SubmittedDate.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Otherwise, simply cast it beforehand:

```
((DateTime)process.Invoice.SubmittedDate).ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: This worked. I think, SonerGönül and you are right. This wasn't a correct DateTime type. When I have viewed the format it exaclty said: "DateTime?" (I haven't recogized the question mark)

Comment: Fantastic. As it has worked can you please mark the answer as correct, thank you!

Comment: I can not :( It says: "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."